# Excel 2013: Reducing an array (all fields have formulas) to only rows with data

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a worksheet with multiple rows of data taken from elsewhere in the same workbook. The full array goes from A8:W71. The data in these rows are a mixture of numbers and formulas. There are multiple blank rows - where formulas dictate the row should be "".

What I would like to do is copy these full rows to an identical worksheet in the same workbook - but missing the rows where there is no data displayed.

Can anyone suggest? I've tried a number of suggested options - but can't seem to get one to work. I'm a moderately competent Excel user - but no expert. Have been recommended here and this is my first question. Hopefully its clear what I'm asking. Many many thanks - this is driving me dizzy

Comment: Copy and paste the values then sort the range? The empty cells will go to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Scott - I really am looking for either a formula or macro response to automate it as far as possible. Im building the spreadsheet - but other (who are limited in their experience of Excel) will use it from there. Need to do this for them therefore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**
This should do the trick:

```
 Sub CopyRows()
    ' Clear TargetSheet Data
    Worksheets("TargetSheet").Rows("2:64").ClearContents
    Dim rowCount As Long, i As Long
    With Worksheets("SourceSheet")
        For i = 8 To 71
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Rows(i), ">""") > 0 Then
                PasteRows i
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub PasteRows(i As Long)
    Dim rowCount As Long
    With Worksheets("TargetSheet")
        rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("SourceSheet").Rows(i).Copy
        .Cells(rowCount, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

**Reedited...lol Thanks CMArg's!!**
My approach was a little verbose.  I tried to make it somewhat generic.

I refactored CMArg's combined code for readability

```
Private Sub CopyRows()
    Dim i As Integer, count As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim s As Worksheet, t As Worksheet
    Set s = Worksheets("SourceSheet")
    Set t = Worksheets("TargetSheet")
    k = 1
    For i = 8 To 71
        count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(s.Rows(i), ">""")
        If count > 0 Then
            k = k + 1
            t.Rows(k).EntireRow.Value = s.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Folks: Thanks so much for your response. Both of these work - I've used the one by Thomas as  with my limited skill level I find it easier to understand. Many thanks also to CMArg.

HOWEVER - could you help with one refinement of Thomas's excellent solution? If data is updated in "Sourcesheet" and then the macro is re-run - it adds a new set of rows in "Targetsheet" below the last complete set of rows. Ideally - I would like it to replace the previous entry. The data should always be in A8:W71 and start at A8. Thank you once again for your support.

Comment: My code always starts in row 8 (the k value). In Thomas code, you are counting the rows in TargetSheet and adding 1 (`rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`), and then pasting the data there (`.Cells(rowCount, 1).PasteSpecial...` etc). Maybe you can add a variable inside the first if (`If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Rows(i), ">""") > 0 Then`) to account for the first event (like the `temp` variable in my code), and afterwards go on with Thomas code.

Comment: I added Worksheets("TargetSheet").Rows("2:64").ClearContents to the start of the macro to clear out the old data.  You might need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: I've merged Thomas code with mine (see edit). I think is much simpler now (approaching the "two-lines code" I already mentioned..).

Comment: Fantastic. Works like a dream. Thanks very much - have learnt a lot from this.

Comment: @ThomasInzina, `t.Rows(i - 7).EntireRow.Value` will leave blank rows in TargetSheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty shure that someone will come with a compact, two-lines code. But the brute code below does what you want.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim temp As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

temp = 0
k = 8 ' first row for pasting results
For i = 8 To 71 'the rows
    For j = 1 To 23 ' the columns
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j) <> "" Then 'if there is something in the cell, temp will no longer be 0
            temp = temp + 1
        End If
    Next
        If temp > 0 Then 'if there is something in the row, copy the row to sheet2
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, 1).EntireRow.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
            k = k + 1 'next row in Sheet2
            temp = 0 'reset for next row in sheet1
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

**EDITED** A combination of previous answers, condensed. Code is much simpler now.

```
Private Sub CopyRows()
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer

k = 8 ' first row for pasting results
For i = 8 To 71 'the rows
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SourceSheet").Rows(i), ">""") > 0 Then 'if there is something in the cell
            Worksheets("TargetSheet").Cells(k, 1).EntireRow.Value = Worksheets("SourceSheet").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
            k = k + 1
        End If
Next
End Sub
```